# How to Keep Session alive in asp.ner MVC after solution rebuild in visual studio

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session

I am working on MVC project which is configured to use local IIS web server in visual studio. Whenever I rebuild the solution I logout due to session cleanup. And hence it takes more time in development. Is there a way to maintain this session until and unless session does not expire or cleanup explicitly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are using [asp.net/identity] (http://www.asp.net/identity) then you can opt to remember User.
But the title of your Question is appearing incorrect of what you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you loose sessionstate is because you are using sessionstate InProc. Because your process is restarted you loose everything contained in there.

Set up an ASP.NET session state service which is a windows service and connect to it.

https://youtu.be/z4rpYK4DNoI

Comment: Thanks, I configured sessionstate and it resolved my issue.

Comment: No problem but you must accept if it is the right answer.